# In video-js how to create a custom event?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, dom-events, video.js

I need to create a custom event in video JS that fires at a certain point during the play back.

For example:

```
player.on('timeupdate',function(){
    if(player.currentTime> 50){
        // trigger some custom event like 'played50Second'
    }
});
```

and then later I want to do:

```
player.on('played50Second',function(evt){
    console.log('Great Job, you played 50 second of the video!!!')
});
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`player.trigger('played50Second');`

You probably want to make sure you only trigger that once rather than every time `currentTime()` is greater than 50. `currentTime` is a function in the video.js API, so `player.currentTime() > 50`.

```
    var player = videojs('my_player');
    var timeCheck = function() {
      if (player.currentTime() > 50) {
        player.off('timeupdate', timeCheck);
        player.trigger('played50Second');
      }
    };
    player.on('played50Second', function(){
      console.log('...');
    });
    player.on('timeupdate', timeCheck);
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful